# SharedElementTransition between 2 activities isn't animating properly

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I've been working on trying to the my sharedELementTransitions working nice and smooth. But I have a problem where my ImageView jumps and doesn't scale properly on the return animation. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAqbu.jpg) I've tried copying pre existing android projects as much as possible even projects that run perfect animations with nearly identical code, and nothing seems to fix it. Has anyone had any similar problems? If so, how did you fix it?

Comment: pls share what have you tried so far

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 2):

Check this solution it is working for me (Both exit and return transitions are working)

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageListItem);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.DummyText);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

            Pair<View, String> p1 = Pair.create((View) textView, "newTrans");
            Pair<View, String> p2 = Pair.create((View) imageView, "profileAnimation");

            ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this, p1, p2);
            startActivity(intent, optionsCompat.toBundle());

        }
    });

    listview.setAdapter(new DummyAdapter());

}

private class DummyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 20;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        return convertView;

    }
}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.hb.androidlanimations.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"></ListView>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageListItem"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:transitionName="profileAnimation" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/DummyText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="DummyText"
    android:transitionName="newTrans" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
}
}
```

activity_second.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:paddingTop="30dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgMain"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:transitionName="profileAnimation" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/DummyActivity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Dummy Text"
    android:transitionName="newTrans" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

use this item inside your style :

```
  <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
```

Comment: Thank you it seem smy problem was that I was using a SubSamplingImageView not an actual imageview so it wasn't animating the change in bounds